# Problema no hiperlink para ligação com números de telefone

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um campo dentro de uma tabela, onde trás do banco o dado telefone, numa string formato `(xxx) xxxx-xxxx` . Eu quero no momento em que clicar no telefone, abrir a opção para escolher qual programa vou usar para fazer a ligação. (por exemplo o skype). 
Eu usei o formato `<a href=\"tel:"+properties.telefone+"\">`
Ele faz abrir a opção e até escolher o programa,  mas ele pega apenas o `(xxx)` e não o telefone completo `(xxx) xxxx-xxxx`
O que pode ser?

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa eu usei apenas o <a href=\"tel:"+properties.telefone+"\">

Comment: Não é por causa do espaço entre o ) e o x? Vc tentou (xxx)xxxx-xxxx tudo junto sem espaço?

Comment: Difícil saber sem o código, pode ser um monte de coisa.

Comment: @hugocsl eu usei apenas esse código nada mais. Eu pensei que poderia ser o espaço, mas isso já vem do banco, não tem como tratar isso no front?  Tirar esse espaço? Esse campo tá dentro de uma td.

Comment: Tente com o telefone no formato `xxx-xxxx-xxxx`.

Comment: @Isa tenta alguma forma de *tratar esse espaço* para ver se resolve. Ou vamos aguardar pra ver se alguém tem mais alguma dica.

Answer (score 3):

Procure colocar um link sem nenhum caractere especial como:

```
<a href="tel:9999999999">(99) 9999-9999</a>
```

Com o seu JS no caso já tratando isso:

```
'<a href="tel:'+properties.telefone.replace(/\(|\)| |\-/g, '')+'">(99) 9999-9999</a>'
```

Comment: É assim mesmo?o meu não foi

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que algo desse tipo deve te ajudar! Caso Negativo, explique melhor o que precisa para eu conseguir lhe ajudar.

```js
var telefone_banco='(012) 3456-7890'; 

var tel_sem_espaco=telefone_banco.replace(" ","");

var tel_sem_hifen=tel_sem_espaco.replace("-","");

var tel_sem_parenteses=tel_sem_hifen.replace("(","").replace(")","");

var telefone = tel_sem_parenteses;

/* Continua seu código */
```